# ios "Data Loading" Notification with transparent background

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, transparency

I am trying to create a view in iOS to let the user know their data is loading... it should have about a 200x200 Rounded-corner box in the middle with a spinner and the words "Data Loading..." and a transparent background.

This all is working except my 200x200 rounded-corner box is also transparent.

Here is the code I am using:

```
UIView *loadingDataView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 367)];
loadingDataView.alpha = 0.4;
loadingDataView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIView *viewWithSpinner = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 106, 100, 100)];
[viewWithSpinner.layer setCornerRadius:15.0f];
viewWithSpinner.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UILabel *msg = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 75, 90, 20)];
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 90, 70)];
spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
[spinner startAnimating];
msg.text = @"Data Loading";
msg.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
msg.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
msg.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
msg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
viewWithSpinner.opaque = NO;
viewWithSpinner.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[viewWithSpinner addSubview:spinner];
[viewWithSpinner addSubview:msg];
[loadingDataView addSubview:viewWithSpinner];
[self.view addSubview:loadingDataView];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution** for your problem is that you should remove the alpha attribute of 0.4, that's what's turning your round view transparent, if your view is set to `clearColor` (this is not really a color, it just makes the view transparent) it makes no sense to add an alpha of 0.4. If what you want is a semi-transparent view surrounding your black rounded view, you should do the following:

```
[loadingDataView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 andAlpha:0.4]];
```

That will give you something whiteish kinda grayish, that should work.

**However**, I would recommend you to use the [GIDAAlertView](https://github.com/GIDAIbero/GIDAAlertView) Class I developed, you can get the source and an example app on my GitHub:

It takes about 3 lines to get it working:

```
GIDAAlertView *spinnerAlert=[[GIDAAlertView alloc] initAlertWithSpinnerAndMessage:@"GIDAAlertView Spinner"];

//Show it ...  
[spinnerAlert presentAlertWithSpinner];

//Later in your code, hide it 
[spinnerAlert hideAlertWithSpinner];
```

This is how it looks [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT3iO.jpg).

Answer (score 6):

No exactly an answer to your question, but check out the open source [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). It aims to be an open source replacement for the private `UIProgressHUD` class, and is exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Btw... I used this an I love it!

Answer (score 0):

you are telling it to be clear...

```
loadingDataView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

What do you want it to be black?

Comment: I want the background (everything around the 200x200) to be semi-transparent (alpha of .3)...